# Read multiple RFID readers into Excel

Tags: excel, rfid

I use Excel to build a demo program for RFID readers. I want to have 3 readers (HID) feeding 3 different cells at the same time. The reader I'm using is pcProx made by RF Ideas. I connected them to USB ports on the Windows 7 PC running Office 10. I can see all three readers on different ports in device manager, but only got one location (in current active cell) in Excel I can read. To Excel, it seems all inputs are from one reader, rather than three.

What do I put in each cell to read 3 different USB RFID reader at the same time?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I searched site and could not find answer to the question.  Please stop voting me down without any feedback.  If it was answered in the past, at least please point me to the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your question was downvoted because it had been asked before. Your question is of very poor quality: You don't explain what you tried so far, you don't mention what RFID readers & how they are connected, you don't explain what data you expect the cells to be filled with, ...

Comment: Mr. Roland, thanks for your constructive comments.  The reader I'm using is pcProx made by RF Ideas.  I connected them to USB ports on the Windows 7 PC running Office 10.  I can see all three readers on different ports in device manager, but only got one location (in current active cell) in Excel I can read.  To Excel, it seems all inputs are from one reader, rather than three.

Comment: Please modify Original Post instead of in Comment. You are saying that the Readers will just dump output to ActiveCell and have no way to tell which Reader it is from? If so, it seems normal unless you can get Excel to have direct interaction with the Readers - contact support from RF Ideas about it. There should be some Reference in Excel you can add to gain control of the Readers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read that [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728071/reading-hid-proxy-card-in-windows-store-app/) first as it explains the problematic of using RFID readers that emulate keystrokes. To sum it up: You can't distinguish between keystrokes from a keyboard and any other device connected as "virtual" keyboard, they are all the same. An application will receive them as key-down and key-up events and won't be able to recognize their exact source.

What you could do, however, with those pcProx readers is the following: According to the [product description](http://rfideas.com/products/pcprox_readers/pcprox_enroll/index.php), you can configure the reader to "add keystrokes before and after the card's data". With regard to Excel I would suggest you configure the following keystrokes to be sent before the card data:

- Function key F5
- Cell name (e.g. B2), different for each of the three readers
- Enter key

That way, each reader would jump to the correct cell first. Keep in mind, though, that if the readers type simultaneously, they would interfere with each other.